# Sometimes i get unknow error in powershell on windows server 2016

Tags: node.js, powershell, windows-server-2016

Sometimes i get unknow error in powershell on windows server 2016, every time this error have random behavior, but every time is "Fatal error", like on screenshot.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Unknown type: 541

#
# Fatal error in, line 0
# unreachable code
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000007BD8BFF1F0
```

What is that and how to fix this? I launch node.js on this server

Memory leak? 
Disc error?

P.S. on Linux server i dont have any errors, but i need to launch my code on Windows server 2016. Sorry if my question was stupid or is a duplicate.